# Images and text in a figure - LATEX

Tags: graphics, positioning, text

I have currently got a table summarizing some gates and its operations but it looks out of place and the format isn't correct. 
Does anyone know how to align the images with the text? 
Also in the 'effect' column, I would like the text one underneath the other. 
Please see Latex code below and the image attached.

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering 
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    %{m{15mm} m{70mm} m{18mm}}
    Gates  & Circuit Symbol & Matrix Representation & Effect\\
     \midrule\midrule



Pauli-X  & 

\includegraphics[scale = 1 , trim= {50 50 32 25}, clip
]{Chapter2/Figs/Raster/x.png} &

$U(\pi, 0 , \pi) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1& 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ &

\begin{itemize}
\item $\emph{X}\ket{0}\longrightarrow\ket{1}$ 
\item $\emph{X}\ket{1}\longrightarrow\ket{0}$
\end{itemize}

\\%new row

Pauli-Y  & 

\includegraphics[scale = 1 , trim= {50 50 32 25}, clip
]{Chapter2/Figs/Raster/y.png} &    

$U(\pi , \frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ & 

\begin{itemize}
\item $\emph{Y}\ket{0}\longrightarrow i\ket{1}$ 
\item $\emph{Y}\ket{1}\longrightarrow-i\ket{0}$,
\end{itemize}

\\%new row

Pauli-Z  & 

\includegraphics[scale = 1 , trim= {50 50 32 25}, clip
]{Chapter2/Figs/Raster/z.png} &

$U(0 , 0 , \pi) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$ & 

\begin{itemize}
\item $\emph{Z}\ket{0}\longrightarrow\ket{0}$  
\item $\emph{Z}\ket{1}\longrightarrow-\ket{1}$
\end{itemize}

\\%new row

Hadamard  &
\includegraphics[scale = 1 , trim= {50 50 32 25}, clip
]{Chapter2/Figs/Raster/h.png} & 

$U(\frac{\pi}{2},0 , \pi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$ &

\begin{itemize}
\item $\emph{H}\ket{0}\longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{0}+\ket{1})$  
\item $\emph{H}\ket{1}\longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{0}-\ket{1})$  \end{itemize}

\\% end of rows
    \midrule\midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
  \caption{Names, circuit symbols and unitary matrix representation for common single qubit gates.}

\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
  \end{figure}
```

[image: - Latex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you check the bounding boxes of the images? Other thatn that, try usingthe ke `valign=c` for `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Why is the caption placed inside of the `tablenotes` environment and why is a table placed inside of a `figure` environment? Please clarify. Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: `itemize` inside of a `c` type column will not work but give error messages such as "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."  instead.

Answer (score 1):

To vertically center your image inside a table cell, you can use `\raisebox{-0.5\height}` before the `\includegraphics`. Using a simple table and standard example-image, this is what you get with and without `\raisebox{-0.5\height}`

[image]

The complete code is

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
%
%
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Vertical centering of figures in cells.}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
        Column1 & Column2 & Column3 \\
        \midrule
        Cols1 & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}} & Cols3 \\
        Cols1 & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}} & Cols3 \\
        Cols1 & Cols2 & Cols3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{NO vertical centering of figures in cells.}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
        Column1 & Column2 & Column3 \\
        \midrule
        Cols1 & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} & Cols3 \\
        Cols1 & \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image} & Cols3 \\
        Cols1 & Cols2 & Cols3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%

\end{document}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion using `valign=c` that comes with the `adjustbox` package. I have also added a customized version of `itemize` for the use inside of this table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{wide=0pt, leftmargin= * ,label=\textbullet}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

  \centering 
%  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cccm{37mm}}
    %{m{15mm} m{70mm} m{18mm}}
    Gates  & Circuit Symbol & Matrix Representation & Effect\\
     \midrule\midrule



Pauli-X  & 

\includegraphics[width=1cm, valign=c]{example-image} &

$U(\pi, 0 , \pi) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1& 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ &

\begin{tabitem}
\item $\emph{X}\ket{0}\longrightarrow\ket{1}$ 
\item $\emph{X}\ket{1}\longrightarrow\ket{0}$
\end{tabitem}

\\%new row

Pauli-Y  & 

\includegraphics[width=1cm, valign=c]{example-image} &    

$U(\pi , \frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ & 

\begin{tabitem}
\item $\emph{Y}\ket{0}\longrightarrow i\ket{1}$ 
\item $\emph{Y}\ket{1}\longrightarrow-i\ket{0}$,
\end{tabitem}

\\%new row

Pauli-Z  & 

\includegraphics[width=1cm, valign=c]{example-image} &

$U(0 , 0 , \pi) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$ & 

\begin{tabitem}
\item $\emph{Z}\ket{0}\longrightarrow\ket{0}$  
\item $\emph{Z}\ket{1}\longrightarrow-\ket{1}$
\end{tabitem}

\\%new row

Hadamard  &
\includegraphics[width=1cm, valign=c]{example-image} & 

$U(\frac{\pi}{2},0 , \pi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$ &

\begin{tabitem}
\item $\emph{H}\ket{0}\longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{0}+\ket{1})$  
\item $\emph{H}\ket{1}\longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{0}-\ket{1})$  
\end{tabitem}

\\% end of rows
    \midrule\midrule
    \end{tabular}
%    \begin{tablenotes}
%
%\end{tablenotes}
%\end{threeparttable}
    \caption{Names, circuit symbols and unitary matrix representation for common single qubit gates.}

  \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```